# Como inserir a conexão dentro das funções sem repetir as instuções?

Tags: php, pdo, funções

Visto que eu tenho várias funções que vão usar esta conexão, como inserir o `$pdo` dentro da função sem copiar o `require` e `$pdo` dentro de cada uma das funções que vou elaborar?

```
require("classes/Database.php");
$pdo  = Database::connect();

function inserir (){

}
function listar (){

}
function atualizar (){

}

function excluir(){

  if ($_GET['tipo'] == 'blog' && $_GET['funcao'] == 'excluir'){

    $pdo->query("DELETE FROM tb_blog WHERE ID = " . $_GET['id'] . "");
    echo "
      <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL='>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.location = \"index\";
      </script>
      ";
    return;
  }

}
excluirDados();
```

Comment: Pode passar `$pdo` como argumento para função ...  `$_GET` também deveria ser variáveis globais ou externas não devem ser injetadas diretamente assim. Outra opção é criar uma classe para compartilha `$pdo` entre os métodos.

Comment: ... **passar como argumento para a função** ... pode me demonstrar isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode passar `$pdo` como argumento para as funções ou criar uma classe para compartilha a conexão entre o métodos. Não injecte variáveis globais ou externas dentro de um função pois elas podem quebra o comportamento da função que é um pedaço de código reaproveitavel.

```
function novo ($pdo, $registro){

}
function listar ($pdo){

}
function atualizar ($pdo, $registro){

}

function excluir($pdo, $id){

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM tb_blog WHERE ID = ?");
    if(!$stmt->execute(array($id))){
       print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    }
    echo "
      <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL='>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.location = \"index\";
      </script>
      ";
    return;
  }

}


 if (!empty($_GET['tipo']) && $_GET['tipo'] == 'blog' && !empty($_GET['funcao']) && $_GET['funcao'] == 'excluir'){
    $id = !empty($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id'] ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
    excluir($pdo, $id);
}
```

Abordagem com classe, não repeti a validação com `$_GET` mas ela ainda necessária, use a função `header()` para redirecionar o usuário não faz sentido usar javascript para isso

```
class blogDAO{
    private $connection;

    function __construct(PDO $pdo){
        $this->connection = $pdo;
    }

    function novo($registro){

    }
    function listar(){

    }
    function atualizar ($pdo, $registro){

    }

    function excluir($id){

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("DELETE FROM tb_blog WHERE ID = ?");
        if(!$stmt->execute(array($id))){
            print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

}

$daoBlog = new blogDAO(Database::connect());

if($_GET ...){
    if($daoBlog->excluir($id)){
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        echo 'erro ...';
    }
}
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo fazer o listar ... **listar();** Tá dando erro no meu código quando eu chamo a função dessa forma. Pode demonstrar na própria resposta pf.

Comment: rray muitooooo obrigado pela sua resposta mas ainda estou trilhando os caminhos do POO, já entendo muita coisa que está ai mas ainda tenho dificuldade em usar TUDO ISSO. Por enquanto uma solução com as **functions** vai resolver, mas com certeza futuramente vou usar sua classe.

Comment: **function listar()** o tempo todo **Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object on line 12 >>> foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $linha) { ?>**

Comment: @MarcosVinicius parece que a conexão `$pdo` não é válida.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius coloca ai o código do listar e a chamada dele. Não deve ser extenso.

Answer (score 2):

A ideia do `@rray` de passar `PDO` como argumento realmente é excelente.

Apenas como complemento, é possível induzir o tipo do parâmetro para que seja passado sempre o `PDO`.

Exemplo:

```
function excluir(\PDO $pdo, $id) {
    $pdo->query(/*...*/);
}
```

Nesse caso, se passar outra coisa que não seja a instância de um `PDO`, um erro fatal será gerado.

Isso pode fazer com que seu código fique mais legível para outros programadores ;)

Exemplo:

```
$pdo = new PDO(/* Dados para conexão **/);

excluir($pdo, 5);
```

Ou ainda:

```
$ob = new MinhaClasse

$ob->excluir($pdo, 5);
```